# Error while retrieving contacts with Oauth

Tags: android, oauth

I'm facing a problem with connecting to https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ website, it giving me the error 401.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information for this question to be meaningful. How did you get a token? How did you send it? What HTTP client are you using? On what Android version? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 implies you are not authorised to view the page, so whatever credentials you are providing dont seem to be correct.